# High level deferred/promise advice

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that has the following structure:

```
doSomething '/', ->
  waitForthis '#e', ->
    waitForSomethingElse '#el', ->
      #actually do it
```

If I wanted to use deferreds/promises to be something like this:

```
doSomething().then(waitForthis).then(waitForSomethingElse);
```

Where would I create the deferred and would each then return a promise?

I am just looking for some rough advice to get me started.

I will probably use jquery deferreds for this.

Answer (score 0):

(assuming jQuery)

To ensure chaining, each step needs to return a promise.

That's what then() does, so no problem here.

doSomething() also needs to return a promise. You'll do this by making doSomething() create a deferred, and return its promise.

Some jQuery functions already include a deferred, and you can directly chain them with then(). For example:

```
$.ajax(...).then(...)
```

Check out [this article](http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/) for more details and live examples.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for something like:

```
Send request A
when A returns,
Send request B(result a)
when B returns,
Do C(response b)
```

Then you need to make each one a promise, and you need to pay attention to closures (because you can't collect the return value from a callback).

```
a_done = something_that_returns_a_promise();
a_done.then(function (a_result) {
    var b_done = something_that_returns_a_promise(a_result);
    b_done.then(function (b_result) { do_C(b_result); });
});
```

If you're looking for something like

```
Send request A
Send request B

when A && B return,
Do C
```

Then you're looking at a function which will take a number of promises, and return a promise.

```
a = something_returning_a_promise();
b = something_returning_a_promise();
a_and_b_done = when(a, b);

a_and_b_done.then(function (result1, result2) { do_c(result1, result2); })
            .then(show_results);
```

Doing something like

```
a_done.then(fillRows).then(showResults);
```

Doesn't let you make multiple async calls...  ...what it does is allows you to chain a bunch of synchronous tasks one after the other (or make async calls where the order they arrive in doesn't matter at all).

```
.then
```

or

```
.done
```

or whatever, doesn't do anything special -- it adds a task to an array.
When the async promise returns (or if it's already returned and has been resolved), it just goes through that list in order, and fires all of the callbacks, passing whatever data it was resolved with (and calling the "success" or "failure" callbacks, based on the success of the operation).

So you need one promise for each async callback, and if you're trying to chain callbacks together, you still need to wrap each one inside of a closure (the closure which will pass the result to whatever is constructing your next promise).

I'm using the jQuery `$.Deferred()`, `deferred.promise()`, `deferred.resolve()`, `deferred.reject()`, `promise.done()`, `promise.fail()` and `$.when()` here:
other libraries might have different terminology, but will behave similarly.

```
var ImageLoader = function (name, format) {
    var loading = $.Deferred(),

        img = new Image(),
        url = name + (format || ".png");

    img.onload = function () {
        loading.resolve(img);
    };

    img.onerror = function () {
        loading.reject("Image failed to load:" + name);
    };

    img.src = url;

    return loading.promise();
};


var imgLoaded = ImageLoader("//mysite.com/myimg");

imgLoaded.done(function () { console.log("img 1 loaded"); });
imgLoaded.fail(function (msg) { console.log(msg); });

var img2Loaded = ImageLoader("//yoursite.com/yourimg", ".jpg");
img2Loaded.done(function () { console.log("img 2 loaded"); });
img2Loaded.fail(function (msg) { console.log(msg); });


var showImages = function (img1, img2) {
    document.body.appendChild(img1);
    document.body.appendChild(img2);
};

var both_loaded = $.when(imgLoaded, img2Loaded);
both_loaded.done(showImages);
```

This is a messy and convoluted example, but rather than making it elegant, I figured I'd try to write it in a way that shows all of the pieces.

Answer (score 0):

> something like this:
>
> `doSomething().then(waitForthis).then(waitForSomethingElse);`

It rather would be

```
doSomething('/').then( function() {
    return waitForthis('#e');
}).then( function() {
    return waitForSomethingElse('#el');
});
```

Or you use [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

> Where would I create the deferred and would each then return a promise?

Yes, each function would return a promise. In jQuery, "Deferred" is the constructor for the deferred object, calling "promise()" returns an object which only has the addCallback functions, but does not expose the trigger methods. Just check [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) and its many examples.